# Why does np.arange(0.6, 0.68, 0.01) include 0.68?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I was testing a code in the console and got this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(0.6, 0.68, 0.01)
array([0.6 , 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.66, 0.67, 0.68])
>>> np.arange(0.6, 0.69, 0.01)
array([0.6 , 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.66, 0.67, 0.68])
>>> np.arange(0.6, 0.70, 0.01)
array([0.6 , 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.66, 0.67, 0.68, 0.69])
```

Why does `np.arange(0.6, 0.68, 0.01)` include the number 0.68?

I suppose this might be a problem with the numerical accuracy, but I don't know why.

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987)

Comment: This is not a full explanation, but neither 0.68 nor 0.69 nor 0.7 can be represented exactly, all of them are "rounded" to the nearest floating-point value, which is slightly smaller for 0.69 and 0.7, but slightly larger for 0.68.

Answer (score 3):

From the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

> For floating point arguments, the length of the result is ceil((stop -
> start)/step). Because of floating point overflow, this rule may result
> in the last element of out being greater than stop.

In this case:

```
>>> (0.68 - 0.6)/0.01
8.000000000000007
```

Taking the ceiling of that gives you `9`, which means numerical accuracy is indeed to blame here.
The documentation recommends using [`np.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace) instead when specifying a non-integer step.

Comment: Not sure what "floating point overflow" has to do with this, none of the numbers are anywhere near overflowing.

Answer (score 3):

Beyond the fact that floating point representation is the culprit here, which others have explained quite well, a way around the issue could be to build the range using integers (which have no such representation issues) and divide by the precision scale:

```
np.arange(60,68,1)/100

array([0.6 , 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.66, 0.67])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a floating point issue.

`0.68` is actually `0.68000000000000004884981308350688777863979339599609375`, thus above `0.68` and will include `0.68` in the `arange`.

If you take `0.69` which is actually `0.689999999999999946709294817992486059665679931640625` (**below** `0.69`) then you indeed have:

```
np.arange(0.6, 0.69, 0.01)
# array([0.6 , 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.66, 0.67, 0.68])
```

There's actually warning about it in the [`arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) documentation:

> The length of the output might not be numerically stable.
>
> Another stability issue is due to the internal implementation of
> numpy.arange. The actual step value used to populate the array is
> dtype(start + step) - dtype(start) and not step. Precision loss can
> occur here, due to casting or due to using floating points when start
> is much larger than step. This can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @mkrieger1 that's true I think it's because of the numerical stability mentioned in the documentation, if you take `0.67` that has a lower imprecision the value is not present.

Comment: `0.68` isn't above `0.68`.